# Converting varchar to int using phpmyadmin

Tags: sql, mysql, type-conversion

I'm trying to convert a table from `varchar` to `int`. The reason for this is because I'm trying to order the numbers on my website by the highest first. That's not the problem but because it's a variable it's ordering them wrong.

When I try changing the table in PhpMyAdmin to an `INT` I get this error:

> 1283 - Column 'referrals' cannot be part of FULLTEXT index

Maybe there's a query I have to put in. All help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You have a full text index associated with your `referrals` column that needs to be dropped before the data type change will successfully execute:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table DROP INDEX (fulltext_index_name);
```

But check before you drop the index to see if it references other columns in the table, because you'll need to recreate the index (excluding the `referrals` column) for Full Text Search to work.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply!!Im sure it works I just need a little more help.. I've used your solution like this ALTER TABLE referrals DROP INDEX (fulltext_index_name) do I have to put something into the index_name bit? Thankyou!

Comment: @Martin Cooper: Yes, you need to specify the name of the full text index that referrals is attached to.  Use the [SHOW INDEX syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-index.html) to find the name.  You want to look at your table in particular, where the `index_type` is "fulltext".

Comment: Hmm.. I get this error 1142 - SELECT command denied to user '***********' for table 'pb_users'

Comment: @Martin Cooper: You need to use an account with higher privileges, or increase the privilege to the `pb_users`

Comment: Hmm.. This is the account 1and1 have given me.. I am the main admin.. Ok well I have the solution. Thankyou you've been VERY helpful!!! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the myadmin interface to do the changes.

Just go to the Table you wish to change and click on it.
then go to structure on the menu tabs at the top.
and click change next to the field you would like to change. it will allow you to modify everything about that field and the table.